# График множества кривых

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Есть таблица в файле вида

```
Nan x1  x2  x3 ...
y1  z11 z12 z13 Nan 
y2  z21 .
y3  Nan   .
.           .
.
.
```

`Nan` означает отсутствие значения. Необходимо построить график зависимости `z_ij` от `y_i` (по оси абсцисс будут `y`, ординат - `z`). Получится множество точек. А далее соединить точки `z_ij`, относящиеся к одному столбцу `x_i` кривыми, чтобы в результате график выглядел как множество кривых на одной плоскости. Как такое сделать с помощью `pandas` и `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Таблицу уже прочитал с помощью `pandas.read_table()`. Когда подаю это в `pyplot.plot()`, то получаю неправильную ориентацию осей, как её изменить? Ещё желательно получить легенду, что такая-то кривая соответствует такой-то колонке `x_i`.

upd: Вот вывод `print(table.head())`

```
       0     1     2     3      4    5    6
0    NaN  0.01  0.03  0.10  0.300  1.0  4.0
1 -50.00  0.09   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
2 -14.00  0.51  0.30   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
3 -30.00  0.20  0.16  0.12    NaN  NaN  NaN
4 -10.21  0.25  0.69  0.15  0.055  NaN  NaN
```

upd2: Вот что должно получится (без 5 и 6 столбцов):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы можете привести пример ваших данных - например вывод команды: `print(df.head())`?

Comment: @MaxU обновил вопрос

Comment: @MaxU Nan могут быть в разных местах, не только такого вида

Comment: столбец `0` - соответствует `y` из вашего вопроса?

Comment: @MaxU да ______

Answer (score 1):

У меня получается нормально нарисовать графики только если избавиться от NaN's по оси `X` и отсортировать по столбцу, содержащему значения оси `X` (`0` - в вашем примере):

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]:
       0     1     2     3      4    5    6
0    NaN  0.01  0.03  0.10  0.300  1.0  4.0
1 -50.00  0.09   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
2 -14.00  0.51  0.30   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
3 -30.00  0.20  0.16  0.12    NaN  NaN  NaN
4 -10.21  0.25  0.69  0.15  0.055  NaN  NaN

In [64]: df.assign(x=df['0'].fillna(0)).set_index('x').drop('0',axis=1).sort_index()
Out[64]:
           1     2     3      4    5    6
x
-50.00  0.09   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
-30.00  0.20  0.16  0.12    NaN  NaN  NaN
-14.00  0.51  0.30   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
-10.21  0.25  0.69  0.15  0.055  NaN  NaN
 0.00   0.01  0.03  0.10  0.300  1.0  4.0

In [65]: df.assign(x=df['0'].fillna(0)).set_index('x').drop('0',axis=1).sort_index().plot(marker='o')
Out[65]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x15a8f2b0>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот именно, у меня так же получается. А надо чтобы `-10, -20, ...` были по оси `Ox`, а по `Oy` значения `z_ij`

Comment: Тогда кривые не будут сливаться, а получатся красивыми

Comment: @egor, похоже Pandas не нравятся NaN's по оси `X`...  Я тоже не представляю как графически отобразить точку у которой `X` не определен, а `Y` определен...

Comment: По оси `Ox` здесь `x_i`, а должны быть значения `y`. `x_i` соответствуют кривым

Comment: Т.е. ось `X` - это столбец `1` или `0` из вашего примера?

Comment: По оси `X` должен быть столбец 0 из примера, по оси `Y` всевозможные значения внутри таблицы, т.е. всё, кроме столбца 0 и строки 0 в примере. Строка 0 - названия кривых в легенде

Comment: Если у вас есть libreoffice, то можете построить в нём дефолтный `x,y chart` по таблице из примера, и получится то, что я хочу

Comment: Уже лучше, обновил вопрос

Comment: @egor, я думаю с этим вы справитесь... ;-)